# jQuery Migrate Plugin showing Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-migrate

As per my knowledge, jQuery migrate restores the APIs that were removed, and shows warnings in the browser console when removed and/or deprecated APIs are used. "That way you can spot and fix what otherwise would have been errors." - this is what they say.

I'm using jQuery migrate 1.4.1 with jQuery 2.2.4 and I'm expecting that my existing code will not break. But my code does break in many places.

> [var].replace is not a function
>
> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #itemtarget
>   input[attrValue]!=""

[var] is not a string, hence the error. I understand.
I also understand that changing

```
$('#itemtarget input[attrValue]!=""').each(function () { //code here });
```

to

```
$("#itemtarget").find("input[attrValue != '']").each(function () { //code here });
```

fixes the second error.

But I do not want to be altering my code right now, I was hoping I'll use Migrate Plugin and leave my code as is for the time-being.

Why is migrate plugin causing/not handling these errors?

Comment: Migrate gives you hints about how to migrate, but will not do the work for you. They can't keep every function, otherwise migrate would be a second jquery.

Comment: they're not giving me hints about how I should fix these errors though ...

Answer (score 1):

from the jquery migrate page:

Development vs. Production versions
The production build is minified and does not generate console warnings. It will only generate a console log message upon loading, or if it detects an error such as an outdated version of jQuery that it does not support. Do not use this file for development or debugging, it will make your life miserable.

are you using the minified version?  this will suppress console warnings.